# Facebook C# SDK error

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm following the tutorial for Facebook C# SDK - version 5.2.1 (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

I have a C# project (.net 4) referencing:

- Facebook.Web.dll
- Facebook.Web.Contracts.dll
- Facebook.dll

For some reason, whenever I try using these in a simple asp.net page, I get the following error at runtime:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Web.Contracts' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.....**

Can someone please explain why this is failing ?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Did you get this to work. I have also posted a [entry](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7266081/facebook-contracts-exception) for this issue. Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, worked in my case (ASP.NET Web Site, .NET 4.0, Facebook C# SDK 5.2.1):

- Remove all `*.Contracts.dll` files from your \bin folder
- Download the latest Code Contracts from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992 and install them
- Copy file Microsoft.Contracts.dll from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\PublicAssemblies\v3.5` to your `\bin` folder

Why this whole Contracts thing has to used by Facebook C# SDK remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

remove Facebook.Web.Contracts.dll or any *.Contracts.dll from reference.

Comment: Removing the reference still does not fix the issue 

(Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Web.Contracts' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045))